# Linear Algebra Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

How to solve these questions related to Matrix Inverses in Linear Algebra?

Comment: the question looks a lot like homework. also it is actually 4 questions not 1. questions that don't show effort are usually not liked here. also you should learn latex and writing your questions into text instead of posting a picture. it helps with searching...

Comment: You should be able to find some counterexamples for the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) is false; take a nonzero matrix whose determinant is zero; it is not invertible

Answer (score 0):

$(b)$ is false; if $A$ is an identity matrix and $B=-A$, then we get zero matrix. A Zero matrix is not invertible.